# What does こんなことでいわれても express?

Tags: grammar

I told my friend 頑張って and they replied with:

> こんなことでいわれても

Would the meaning of this be something like:

> Even if this kind of thing is said (it doesn't help)

Comment: You already have the correct answer, so I will say it here.  It is not "this kind of thing" that was said.  It is 頑張って that was said.  You said it in a situation where it did not sound "right".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

で is the instrumental case and in this case it stands for reason, so the sentence can translate into "even if I'm told (of it) for such a (trivial) thing ...".

Answer (score 1):

いわれる is the passive of ''to say'' and is often used to express ''being told'' something. The only weird thing about the sentence is the で. I would say こんなことを言われても to mean ''Even if you tell me such a thing...(it doesn't help)

Comment: A native speaker told me this and I asked about the で and they said it is important but they don't know why. Thank you for letting me know about the passive form of 言う meaning being told. I didn't know that and I think I understand better now what the sentence means. Thank you

Comment: Interesting. I tried to google the version with で but all the sentences that show up use を. You should probably ask your friend about the difference again. Anyways I'm pretty sure the meaning is about the same

Comment: Could you link me to one of those sites? I asked the native speaker and they say it definitely is で。I gave them this translation: "Even by telling me this kind of thing (I wont be happy)" and they said it sounded correct

Comment: Haha, no I literally just typed こんなことでいわれても into google to see what would come up. For example こんなことを言われても困るだけ！... comes up as the 9th result.

Comment: Nothing is weird about the use of  「で」.  It is perfectly correct and natural.